# How do I get a list of all declared classes inheriting from a particular class in C++

Tags: c++, qt, toolchain, gnu-toolchain

I know that isn't exactly possible in C++, but maybe a toolchain that can generate code which has a function, which when called gives me a list of all those classes. For example, across multiple files I have stuff like:

```
class MyClass : public ParticularClass {
    ....
}

class MyClass2 : public ParticularClass {
    ....
}
```

Then, during runtime, I just want a pointer to single instances of the class. Let's say my generated code looks something like this:

```
void __populate_classes() {
    superList.append(new MyClass());
    superList.append(new MyClass2());
}
```

Also, superList would be of type `List<ParticularClass*>`. Plus, I'll be using Qt and `ParticularClass` will be `QObject` derived, so I can fetch the name of the class anyways. I need to basically introspect the class, so my internal code doesn't really bother much about the newly defined type.

So, is there a way to generate this code with some toolchain? If it is possible with `qmake` alone, that'd be like icing on the freaking cake :)

Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Doxygen does a nice job at doing this -- offline. Various IDEs do a nice job at this -- offline. The compiler does not do this. Such knowledge is not needed or used by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Here at work I use a tool called Understand 4 C++. It is a tool that helps you analyze your code. It will do this quite easily. 
But my favorite part is it comes with a C and Perl API which allows you to take advantage of the abstract syntax tree that 'understand' encapsulates and write your own static analysis tools. I have written tons of tools using this API.

Anyways, it's written by SciTools. http://scitools.com and I don't work for them. I just wholeheartedly like their product. In fact I wrote a C# API that wraps their C API and posted it on [CodePlex](http://understandapi.codeplex.com/) a few years ago. Sure beats using C or Perl to write static analysis tools.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you're trying to do is a good idea. Those who will maintain code after you will have hard times to understand it.

Maybe instead of it you'll try see how you can do it in plan C++. One possible solution which comes to mind i to implement factory design pattern. Than you can iterate over all data types in factory and add then to *superList*.

Any way, using [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/) (simple grep replacement) can do the job if you always declare the inheritence in one line:

```
ack ": *public ParticularClass" *.h
```